# Assigning names to internal devices?

Tags: multi-boot

I have a PC I am tinkering with. 
(And forgive me, disclosure, I am used to the Mac environment, where I can get a startup screen and it will show boot drives by their drive name and loaded OS)

This is what I see at my F12'd start up. Is there a way to have this screen show the devices by name or loaded OS? Instead of the drive description as shown?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if the firmware is UEFI and the operating systems were installed to run in UEFI mode as well. Otherwise, the firmware has no method of knowing what operating system is where.

- "MBR" format disks disks have no text labels whatsoever, and the PC BIOS knows *nothing* about the disk's structure: it runs the bootcode found in the 1st sector and that's it. (Traditionally, such tasks as OS selection are done by a separate "boot manager" running *after* the firmware, and providing its own menu.)

  So what you see in a BIOS boot menu is just the drive names from the ATA "Identify device" or SCSI "Inquiry" response from the drive itself. These are hardcoded in the drive's firmware and generally unchangeable.
- UEFI brings in a firmware-managed boot menu, although not always nice-looking and not always useful (e.g. if you have several Windows installations, chances are you'll still end up with a single entry titled "Windows Boot Manager"), but at least it is customizable using `efibootmgr`.

  (UEFI also brings in GPT, which supports assigning text labels to partitions, but unfortunately I've yet to see a firmware that makes use of those.)

Note that new PCs generally do have UEFI, but often come with it switched to only BIOS-emulated boot ("CSM only"). In that case, you could switch it to either hybrid or UEFI-only mode, and convert the existing OS installations to UEFI if they support it.

The alternative is to forget the firmware boot menu and rely entirely on the OS-provided boot manager. Many (especially those provided with Linux) are able to chainload other operating systems, sometimes even detecting Windows automatically. Some are themeable; if you have UEFI, then rEFInd will provide a very Mac-like interface.

Comment: Any way to change the name from HP SDD..... on the drive itself? Or is that hard wired?

Comment: That's usually unchangeable.

Comment: That's it. I appreciate the kind detailed answer. When i settle on which drive is which, I'll just label the front of computer to remind me where the OS is. (I was planning to have Windows and different Linux flavors.)

Comment: Just use the OS-provided boot manager then. For example, Linux GRUB can easily have a menu item to boot (chainload) Windows, whether it is from the same disk or another.